# Multiple React component className's

Tags: reactjs, react-css-modules

We have a React project where styles are written like this:

```
import styles from 'styles/sidebar.module.scss'
...
<div className={styles.sidebar}>Hello</div>
```

I can't figure how to include two classes with this syntax, e.g.:

```
<div className={styles.sidebar}+{styles.scroll}>Hello</div>
<div className={styles.sidebar, styles.scroll}>Hello</div>
<div className={styles.sidebar}, {styles.scroll}>Hello</div>
<div className={styles.sidebar}{styles.scroll}>Hello</div>
```

Nothing from the above works, what else can I try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just like this, because they are just strings:

```
<div className={`${styles.sidebar} ${styles.scroll}`}>Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
<div className={`${styles.sidebar} ${styles.scroll}`}>Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a utility lib called [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) could be a good approach, especially if you need to apply some conditions on whether including some of the class names or not. Here is an example;

```
var classNames = require('classnames');

class Button extends React.Component {
  // ...
  render () {
    var btnClass = classNames({
      'btn': true,
      'btn-pressed': this.state.isPressed,
      'btn-over': !this.state.isPressed && this.state.isHovered
    });
    return <button className={btnClass}>{this.props.label}</button>;
  }
}
```